# Why was "chinese-cuisine" tag removed from my question about 皮蛋?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retag-request

I have recently created [a question about how can one make century eggs at home](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81319/how-to-make-century-eggs), with [eggs](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eggs) and [chinese-cuisine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese-cuisine) tags.

However, [chinese-cuisine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese-cuisine) was shortly removed from question, and I assume this has been done for a reason.

According to Wikipedia,

> **Century egg** or **pidan** (Chinese: 皮蛋; pinyin: *pídàn*), also known as **preserved egg**, **hundred-year egg**, **thousand-year egg**, **thousand-year-old egg**, and **millennium egg**, is a Chinese preserved food product and delicacy made by preserving duck, chicken or quail eggs in a mixture of clay, ash, salt, quicklime, and rice hulls for several weeks to several months, depending on the method of processing.

So, the subject of my question is directly related to Chinese cuisine, and while I am open for any answers, it's highly likely that only users with more or less Chinese heritage would be able to provide an authoritative answer on the matter — while absence of this tag prevents direct exposure of my question to those who can possibly answer it.

So, why was this tag removed then? Should I get it back, and wouldn't it be considered "edit warring", given that user who had removed this tag is top 2% user with 10k+ reputation?

Comment: I don't know why Catija removed it, but we can just ask her directly by @-ing her in comments on the post. (It won't autocomplete, but it does work for editors.) Went ahead and did that. No need to worry about edit wars or anything.

Comment: Feel free to put it back... You ask a question about Thailand and tag it "Chinese-cuisine" and it looks ... troublesome, to say the least. You never mention China in the question, only Thailand. Last time I checked, Thailand is not China. It's even possible that they are different between the two countries.

Comment: @Catija, I can remove a sentence about Thailand not to confuse any readers, but wanted to give a little background. Essentially, Thais, as well as other nationalities of that region, might know the answer, so I don't even know.

Comment: @Catija, and yes, Thailand is not in China, but century eggs originate from China, despite being very popular in Southeast Asia in general.

Comment: I will be completely honest... I'm not really a fan of these tags. At least, not as a "classifier" of questions. I'd rather they were used to mark questions more broadly about a particular nationality's cuisine rather than to tag questions about food that happens to originate there. Does every question about pizza have "italian-cuisine"? - no... or every tag about Macarons "French-cuisine"? - again, no... We're so random with how we use them, their validity is non-existent.

Comment: @Catija Well, maybe we do want to fix how we use those tags (possibly meaning removing them) but that's a separate discussion; if we do want them gone we'll want a cleaner way to go about it.

Comment: There is a bit more than where they originated from. In all the southeast asian countries, some foods and dishes, like these eggs, are currently regarded as chinese. No one in Thailand or Cambodia or the Philippines would regard them as their own food even though they are probably all made locally. There are chinese people (originally emigrated or sold as slaves generations ago) in all of asia. They have adopted local names, but culturally they are slightly different from the indigenous races. Think about certain traditional jewish cuisines, you would not label them European or American.